# Spark SQL: find maximum and sum grouped by key

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark DataFrame with the following schema.

```
counts
 |-- index: string
 |-- name: string
 |-- count: long
```

I would like to sum the `count` column for each `index` and also find the maximum `count` together with its corresponding `name`. So each row would contain a unique `index` with `SUM(count)`, `MAX(count)` and the corresponding `name`.

I group the entries by `index` and select the row with the highest `count` by running the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM counts 
WHERE (index, count) 
IN (
    SELECT index, MAX(count) 
    FROM counts
    GROUP BY index
)
ORDER BY count DESC
```

This works fine and gives me a unique row per `index` containing the row with the highest `count`.

However, I would like to add a column that contains the sum of `count` grouped by `index` based on the original table.

I can sum the view counts and group them by `index` with this query:

```
SELECT index, SUM(count)
FROM counts
GROUP BY index
```

But I would like to have a unified table containing the results of both queries (queried in an efficient way).

Any suggestions on this matter is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use window functions:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT c.*, SUM(count) OVER (PARTITION BY index) as cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY index ORDER BY count DESC) as seqnum
      FROM counts c
     ) c
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

This assumes you have other columns you want to keep.  If you just want the max and the sum for each `index`:

```
SELECT index, MAX(count), SUM(count)
FROM counts
GROUP BY index;
```

And `index` is a bad name for a column, because it is a SQL keyword (think "create index").